# Parse error in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever i run php artisan serve i keep getting errors. I have tried other solutions but still same error. This is the error

parse error, expecting `'&'' or`"variable (T_VARIABLE)"' in /Users/EPDesktop/Project/Backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 475

Comment: @mistermartin I don't find any duplicate. Could my php version be the issue? i am running on 5.5.14

Comment: Yes, PHP version could be an issue. See [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-or-variable-t-variable-in-pathsitevendorlaravelframeworksrcilluminatefoundationhelpersphp-on-line-475).